# Read content of Word file in C# without using Word Application

Tags: c#, ms-word

I"m looking to read the contents of a Word file on an application running on a webserver - without having word installed. Does a native .net solution for this exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. What format is your input document? .doc or .docx?

Comment: @0xA3 good question.  I assumed docx...

Comment: It could be either. If I had to, I could have users convert to .doc before uploading, but that is far from optimal. Realistically, a large majority will be .doc

Comment: Steve's answer below is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aspose makes a paid solution for doing just about anything with any Office format:

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial options too, but that's what [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) is all about as long as you are dealing with docx files only.  If you need doc files, you will probably need to purchase [Aspose's Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i have used several SDK, for now, the best is Aspose.words, the openxml sdk 2.5 is also a nice choice, but the api is too low, so if you use openxml sdk that means will be writing more code, and remenber user openxml sdk tool together, it is a nice tool can make coding simple.
you can look this video for a overview:
[how to use openxml sdk tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA)

another choice: [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/), a commercial option, cheaper than aspose.words.